# How to reformat audio splitted to different blobs?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, recordrtc

I'm recording audio on web browser by `RecordRTC` then sending they to server in small blobs.

First of blobs has headers with codecs and I may just reformat it to any format by `ffmpeg`. All other blobs have no any built-in information and when I'm trying to put they in `ffmpeg` it just answer 'Codec not found'.

Ofc I may just concat they before any manipulations, but I want to stream they continuously to another computer.

So, how may I reformating such files during the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't make sense some blobs arrive with headers and others don't.  There must be something wrong with your logic for creating or uploading the blobs.  The first thought coming to my mind is maybe you are uploading the blobs too soon (ie: before they finish writing).  Make sure you are creating a queue of blobs and do not start upload until totally sure you are done uploading or recording the previous chunk.